# Python date conversion?

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime

I'm currently trying to convert a file format into a slightly different style to allow easier importing into a program however I can't quite get my head around how to convert datetime strings between formats. The original I have is the following:

```
2016-12-15 17:26:45
```

However the required format for the date time is:

```
Thu Dec 15 17:19:03 2016
```

Does anyone know if there is an easy way to convert between these? These values are always in the same place and format so it doesn't need to be too dynamic so to speak outside of recognising what a certain day of the month is (if that can be done at all?)

Update - The conversion has worked for 1 date but not the other weirdly :/ The code to grab the two dates is the following:

```
startDate=startDate.replace("Started : ","")
startDate=startDate.replace(" (ISO format YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS)","")
startDate=startDate.strip()
startDt = datetime.strptime(startDate, '%Y-%m-%d  %H:%M:%S')
startDt=startDt.strftime('%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y ')
print (startDt)
```

This part works as inteded and outputs the required format:

"2016-12-15 17:26:45

Thu Dec 15 17:26:45 2016"

The end date part is a bit "ham fisted" so to speak and I'm sure there are better ways to do the re.sub search just to do anything in brackets but I'll edit that later.

```
endDate=endDate.replace("Ended               : ","")
endDate=endDate.strip()
endDate = re.sub("\(.*?\)", "", endDate)
endDate.strip()
endDt = datetime.strptime(endDate, '%Y-%m-%d  %H:%M:%S')
endDt=endDt.strftime('%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y ')
print (endDt)
```

This part however despite the outputs being an identical format

"2016-12-15 17:26:45

2016-12-15 21:22:11"

produces the following error:

```
endDt = datetime.strptime(endDate, '%Y-%m-%d  %H:%M:%S')    
  File "C:\Python27\lib\_strptime.py", line 335, in _strptime    
    data_string[found.end():])    
ValueError: unconverted data remains:
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime perhaps that link will help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from datetime import datetime

dt = datetime.strptime('2016-06-01  1:33:45', '%Y-%m-%d  %H:%M:%S')
dt.strftime('%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y ')
>>> 'Wed Jun 01 01:33:45 2016'
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this worked for 1 date but the other I get an error of which is 
"ValueError: unconverted data remains:"

However the 2 dates I'm trying to convert are identical in terms of formatting:

1 - 2016-12-15 17:26:45
2 - 2016-12-15 21:22:11

I'm a bit stumped as to why one of these works without issue and the other doesn't work :/ do you have  any ideas?

Comment: There could have been an extra space in the beginning or end, I'd suggest to try doing it again with care in copy-pasting or use the  strip() function.

Comment: I'm currently using .strip() against both dates to remove any whitespace

Comment: Could you perhaps share the code as it would be far more easy for us to help you debug it?

Comment: I've just updated the original post to show the code for these two sections

Answer (score 2):

It's a pretty easy task with the Datetime module.
As it's been pointed out, checking the docs will get you a lot of useful info, starting from the directives to feed to the `strptime` and `strftime` (respectively, parse and format time) functions which you'll need here.

A working example for you case would be:

```
from datetime import datetime

myDateString = '2016-12-15 17:26:45'
myDateObj = datetime.strptime(myDateString, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
myDateFormat = myDateObj.strftime('%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y')
```

Check out [this section of the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) to have a better understanding of the formatting placeholders.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime) module:

```
from datetime import datetime

string = '2016-12-15 17:26:45'
date = datetime.strptime(string, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
date2 = date.strftime("%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z %Y")
print(date2)
```

Output:

> Thu Dec 15 17:26:45  2016